# How do I round a double to two decimal places in Java?

Tags: java, double

This is what I did to round a double to 2 decimal places:

```
amount = roundTwoDecimals(amount);

public double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

This works great if the amount = 25.3569 or something like that, but if the amount = 25.00 or the amount = 25.0, then I get 25.0!  What I want is both rounding as well as formatting to 2 decimal places.

Comment: this function sometimes return , instead of . on android, thus Double.valueOf() throws an exception

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you working with money? Creating a `String` and then converting it back is pretty loopy.

Use `BigDecimal`. This has been discussed quite extensively. You should have a `Money` class and the amount should be a `BigDecimal`.

Even if you're not working with money, consider `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing money. But all I'm doing is tip = (amount * percent)/100 and display tip and amount. I have considered BigDecimal but it seems like going through a lot of pain for such simple calculation. Isn't having a separate money class going overboard in this case?

Comment: Hell no. OO programming means classes are the answer to typing problems. Ask yourself the question: is Money a class of objects? Clearly the answer is yes. If that argument didn't sway you here are 2 more: 1. the Martin Fowler argument from Analysis Patterns: units need to be modeled or bad things happen, and 2. I have a money class I can give you if you like.

Comment: I'm not a pro with OOP but can you guys please tell me what should be the money class contain or do with the topic's situation. I can really figure it out.

Comment: Suggesting someone change a datatype as a solution probably doesn't apply to most working developers.

Comment: Lots of inferences being made by Rob. Great analysis of the down-voter's problem! How about an analysis of the OP question? "I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail." _Maslow

Answer (score 62):

Just use: (easy as pie)

```
double number = 651.5176515121351;

number = Math.round(number * 100);
number = number/100;
```

The output will be 651.52

Comment: he multiplies the number by 100(so 651.517 becomes 65151.7...) and rounds it off to the nearest 1(so it becomes 65152) and then divides it back by 100(651.52).

Comment: You should write 100.0 not 100, otherwise it will treat it as int.

Comment: @Anatoly No - Java evaluates from left to right and expands to the best match of all operands. number is a double, so all participants in calculations with number get expanded to double!

Comment: refer to this answer cause it does not work in a lot of cases  http://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/1798298

Comment: Math.round(0 * 100) / 100 ==>
Output is 0, not 0.00

Comment: It wont give 651.52, it will give 651

Comment: Math.round(num * 100) / 100.00

Answer (score 19):

Use a digit place holder (`0`), as with '`#`' trailing/leading zeros show as absent:

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Comment: well..that didn't work. I still get 25.0.

Comment: I used string formatting to fix this,

    String result = String.format("%.2f", amount);

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment.

Answer (score 13):

Use this

String.format("%.2f", doubleValue) // change 2, according to your requirement.

Comment: Dude you are genius! I've been trying to get this to work for a while. Your comment was it.  lblTotal.setText( String.format("$%.2f",tip) );

Answer (score 8):

You *can't* 'round a double to [any number of] decimal places', because doubles don't have decimal places. You can convert a double to a base-10 String with N decimal places, because base-10 does have decimal places, but when you convert it back you are back in double-land, with *binary* fractional places.

Comment: I know. Sorry I didn't express myself properly.

Comment: @sherry you did express yourself properly, you just described an impossible requirement.

Comment: Downvoted. I think the author's intent was obvious. This would have been fine if, like other answers, it had something like, "However, you _can_...".

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider The sentence beginning 'you can ...' meets your objection entirely.

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest i could make it but it gets the job done a lot easier than most examples ive seen.

```
    double total = 1.4563;

    total = Math.round(total * 100);

    System.out.println(total / 100);
```

The result is 1.46.

Answer (score 3):

You can use org.apache.commons.math.util.MathUtils from apache common

`double round = MathUtils.round(double1, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);`

Answer (score 3):

double amount = 25.00;

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

System.out.println(formatter.format(amount));

Comment: You need to explain why this code solves the problem, why this is the best solution etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Commons Math:

```
Precision.round(double x, int scale)
```

source: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html#round(double,%20int)

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2):

First declare a object of `DecimalFormat` class. Note the argument inside the `DecimalFormat` is `#.00` which means exactly 2 decimal places of rounding off.

```
private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Now, apply the format to your double value:

```
double input = 32.123456;
System.out.println("double : " + df2.format(input)); // Output: 32.12
```

Note in case of `double input = 32.1;`

Then the output would be `32.10` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your Money class could be represented as a subclass of Long or having a member representing the money value as a native long.  Then when assigning values to your money instantiations, you will always be storing values that are actually REAL money values.  You simply output your Money object (via your Money's overridden toString() method) with the appropriate formatting. e.g $1.25 in a Money object's internal representation is 125.   You represent the money as cents, or pence or whatever the minimum denomination in the currency you are sealing with is ... then format it on output.  No you can NEVER store an 'illegal' money value, like say $1.257.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
public static String getRoundedValue(Double value, String format) {
    DecimalFormat df;
    if(format == null)
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    else 
        df = new DecimalFormat(format);
    return df.format(value);
}
```

or

```
public static double roundDoubleValue(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting java 1.8 you can do more with lambda expressions & checks for null. Also, one below can handle Float or Double & variable number of decimal points (including 2 :-)).

```
public static Double round(Number src, int decimalPlaces) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(src)
            .map(Number::doubleValue)
            .map(BigDecimal::new)
            .map(dbl -> dbl.setScale(decimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))
            .map(BigDecimal::doubleValue)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
double total = Double.valueOf(val);
```

Comment: This solution has the same problem as the original code once you hit numbers above 999.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to two decimal places you can do

```
// assuming you want to round to Infinity.
double tip = (long) (amount * percent + 0.5) / 100.0;
```

This result is not precise but Double.toString(double) will correct for this and print one to two decimal places.  However as soon as you perform another calculation, you can get a result which will not be implicitly rounded. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round` is one answer,

```
public class Util {
 public static Double formatDouble(Double valueToFormat) {
    long rounded = Math.round(valueToFormat*100);
    return rounded/100.0;
 }
}
```

#### Test in Spock,Groovy

```
void "test double format"(){
    given:
         Double performance = 0.6666666666666666
    when:
        Double formattedPerformance = Util.formatDouble(performance)
        println "######################## formatted ######################### => ${formattedPerformance}"
    then:
        0.67 == formattedPerformance

}
```

Comment: with valueToFormat = 0d returns 0.0, not 0.00. Original question asked about two decimal places even in case of 0 value in decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the amount could be positive as well as negative, rounding to two decimal places may use the following piece of code snippet.

```
amount = roundTwoDecimals(amount);

public double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
    if (d < 0)
       d -= 0.005;
    else if (d > 0)
       d += 0.005;
    return (double)((long)(d * 100.0))/100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where num is the double number

- Integer 2 denotes the number of decimal places that we want to print.
- Here we are taking 2 decimal palces

  System.out.printf("%.2f",num);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way that guarantee to output the *myFixedNumber* rounded to two decimal places:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TwoDecimalPlaces {
    static double myFixedNumber = 98765.4321;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(myFixedNumber));
    }
}
```

The result is: ***98765.43***

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 180;
    int j = 1;
    double div=  ((double)(j*100)/i);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); // simple way to format till any deciaml points
    System.out.println(div);
    System.out.println(df.format(div));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public static double roundToDecimals(double number, int c)
{
    String rightPad = StringUtils.rightPad("1", c+1, "0");
    int decimalPoint = Integer.parseInt(rightPad);
    number = Math.round(number * decimalPoint);
    return number/decimalPoint;
}
```