# How to round the double value to 2 decimal points?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [round double to two decimal places in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710394/round-double-to-two-decimal-places-in-java)

I want to round up the double value upto 2 decimal points.

for example: I have  double d=2; and the result should be result =2.00

Comment: Duplicate many questions : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=round+java

Comment: its seems tobe copied the question from below link http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/8793-Doubel-value-round-upto-2-decimal-places.html

Comment: you should accept some answers!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me,This is my requirement i am not copied from any where.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's no difference in internal representation between 2 and 2.00. You can use `Math.round` to round a value to the nearest integer - to make that round to 2 decimal places you could multiply by 100, round, and then divide by 100, but you shouldn't expect the result to be *exactly* 2dps, due to the nature of binary floating point arithmetic.

If you're only interested in *formatting* a value to two decimal places, look at [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) - if you're interested in a number of decimal places *while calculating* you should really be using [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). That way you'll know that you really are dealing with decimal digits, rather than "the nearest available `double` value".

Another option you may want to consider if you're *always* dealing with two decimal places is to store the value as a `long` or `BigInteger`, knowing that it's exactly 100 times the "real" value - effectively storing cents instead of dollars, for example.

Comment: @Rakesh: Are you just trying to *display* values? If so, that's fine... but be aware that, for example, `k` in your last example won't be *exactly* 4.144456 to start with. If exact decimal values matter to you, you shouldn't be using `double`.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet , but plain usage of BigDecimal sometimes doesn't correspondent with output from MsExcell (3,6,9)    `int decimalPlace = 0;
                BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(someDoubleNumber);
                bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace,  BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Comment: @JonSkeet: what is the point of having double when we are not supposed to use it?

Comment: @Amitabh: Where did I say that you shouldn't be using `double` in any circumstances? I was talking about the situation where the exact decimal values are important - in particular with "man-made" values such as currency. `double` is appropriate for natural constructs such as height, weight etc.

Comment: It would be better with an actual static method that provides a solution

Answer (score 68):

```
Math.round(number*100.0)/100.0;
```

Comment: Nice and sweet. No need to user DecimalFormat. This solution shows a better performance for critical enviroments.

Comment: Great solution, it avoids the library call to DecimalFomat! I think it's faster as well.

Comment: Try that with 33.605. When you multiply with 100.0 you get 3360.4999999999995, that will round to 33.60 and not to 33.61 as it should.

Comment: Best solution because it doesn't require any fancy things like external libraries, formatter objects etc.

Answer (score 36):

```
double RoundTo2Decimals(double val) {
            DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        return Double.valueOf(df2.format(val));
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RoundTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double i = 2;    
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println(twoDForm.format(i));
        double j=3.1;
        System.out.println(twoDForm.format(j));
        double k=4.144456;
        System.out.println(twoDForm.format(k));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I guess that you need a formatted output.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",d);
```

Comment: this code is useful for only display how to store.

Comment: String formated = String.format("%.2f",d);

Answer (score 11):

you can also use this code

```
public static double roundToDecimals(double d, int c)  
{   
   int temp = (int)(d * Math.pow(10 , c));  
   return ((double)temp)/Math.pow(10 , c);  
}
```

It gives you control of how many numbers after the point are needed.

```
d = number to round;   
c = number of decimal places
```

think it will be helpful

Answer (score 5):

This would do it.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 12.349678;
        int r = (int) Math.round(d*100);
        double f = r / 100.0;
       System.out.println(f);
     }
```

You can short this method, it's easy to understand that's why I have written like this.

Comment: That will often result in floatingpoint errors

Answer (score 4):

```
public static double addDoubles(double a, double b) {
        BigDecimal A = new BigDecimal(a + "");
        BigDecimal B = new BigDecimal(b + "");
        return A.add(B).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    }
```