# Formatting Double to exactly 2 Decimal places IF required

Tags: java, format, decimal

I require a `DecimalFormat` or a better equivalent of representing a `Double` value (in **Java**) which could be:

25 or 25.5

I need for that to be represented as either a whole number (25) or to two decimal places if it has *any* (25.50). This is because i'm printing it out as **money**.

I have the following format already:

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,###.##");
```

This works perfectly if the `Double` is a whole number; I get the output $25,000. Except if the value is 25,000.5; it prints $25,000.5 when I *need* it to be printed as **$25,000.50**. The problem is as stated in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html):

> #    a digit, zero shows as absent

So essentially the last zero is dropped off since it is optional.

I cannot do:

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,###.#0");
```

as that is not allowed.

**How can I achieve this?**

Note:
These questions are related but do not cover what I need specifically with the `DecimalFormat`. Most of the answers suggest using a `BigDecimal` or `printf`. Is this the best thing to do? I don't *have to* use `DecimalFormat` but prefer to since i've started on that path (lots of code everywhere already using it).

[Best way to Format a Double value to 2 Decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places?rq=1)

[How do I round a double to two decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710394/round-double-to-two-decimal-places-in-java?rq=1)

[Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: did you try `new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");`?

Comment: Yes that gives me two decimal places regardless of the Double having one or not. i.e 25000 becomes 25,000.00 which I do not want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a bit of a hack, but I don't know if the `DecimalFormat` syntax allows for anything better. This simply checks to see if the number is real, and formats based on the spec you asked for.

```
    double number = 25000.5;
    DecimalFormat df;

    if(number%1==0)
         df = new DecimalFormat("##,###");
    else
        df = new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");

    System.out.println(df.format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to return Decimal Format value this works

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
* @return The weight of this brick in kg.
*/
public double getWeight()
{

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    double number = ( getVolume() * WEIGHT_PER_CM3 ) / 1000;

    //System.out.println(df.format(number));

    return Double.valueOf ( df.format( number ) ); 

}
```