# Java toFixed(2) method such js

Tags: java, calculation, tofixed

What is the synonym of JS toFixed(2) method in Java Language.
Only option is DecimalFormat ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I round a double to two decimal places in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710394/how-do-i-round-a-double-to-two-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: Yeah, i used first one

Answer (score 0):

There is none but you can do this as an alternative:

```
/**
* Shortens a float to a specified length
* @param num The float to shorten
* @param to The length
* @return the shortened version
**/
public static String toFixed(float num, int to){
    //Split at the decimal point
    String[] s = String.valueOf(num).split("[.]"); 
    //Combine the two so and shorten the second
    String ending = s[1].substring(0, ((s[1].length() > to) ? to : s[1].length()));
    return s[0] + '.' + ending;
}
```

This doesn't round though

Comment: Thanks for return, i decided to use DecimalFormat. Useful than others