# Java - Decimal Format Precision lost when returning a Float or Decimal

Tags: java, double, precision

I have reviewed a number of threads related to formatting numbers. 
For the most part it works except for the value 3.101.
Float and Double have been used along with the ## and 00 format.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalFormatTest {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Float d1 = -3.1011f;
    Double ds = -3.1011;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println (Double.valueOf(df.format(d1)));
    System.out.println (Double.valueOf(df.format(ds)));

    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    System.out.println (Double.valueOf(df2.format(d1)));
    System.out.println (Double.valueOf(df2.format(ds)));
 }
}
```

The output is :

```
-3.1
-3.1
-3.1
-3.1
```

Expected output :

```
-3.10
-3.10
-3.10
-3.10
```

As mentioned above, this works for all the other numbers I have tested. For some reason this is causing an issue.

Any ideas as to what makes this number so different and what extra step is needed to get the 2nd digit?

Keep in mind, the key is that I want to eventually return a Float or Double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I round a double to two decimal places in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710394/how-do-i-round-a-double-to-two-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your question is.

Comment: Remove the `Double.valueOf` bits and it will work better.

Comment: You are formatting the value correctly, but then re-parsing it as a double (which will shave off the trailing zeros).

Comment: I removed the Double.valueOf and it works using the "#.00" format, but I do need to return a Double and not the string.

Comment: Doubles do not track trailing zeros or precision information. If you want to track those things, doubles are not the right data type to use. (Also, `Double` is a wrapper type, which you shouldn't use unless you specifically need an object instead of a primitive for some reason. Spell it `double` to get the primitive type.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Float d1 = -3.1011f;
        Double ds = -3.1011;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println (df.format(d1));
        System.out.println (df.format(ds));

        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println (df2.format(d1));
        System.out.println (df2.format(ds));
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Double number = 3.101;
System.out.printf("%.2f", number);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit here is `Double.valueOf` . Try removing it and it should work fine like below: 
Also, putting `("#.##")` wil cause further problem . So rather use any `("0.00")` at-least after precision.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalFormatTest {
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Float d1 = -3.1011f;
        Double ds = -3.1011;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println (df.format(d1));
        System.out.println (df.format(ds));

        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println (df2.format(d1));
        System.out.println (df2.format(ds));
     }
}
```

For reference : [Double decimal formatting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806278/double-decimal-formatting-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense in this scenario, but the use of Double.valueOf was because I actually need a Double instead of a string.

Comment: See the reference link.

Comment: @Unhandled - You don't however need the double data type for display purposes. The Double data type drops trailing zeros since there is no need for them. You would only want trailing zeros for display purposes.